# Merging rows from SQL SELECT query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I would like to merge some results from a SQL query. To apply a limit, some rows have to be eliminated while adding some values to another row. The amount of rows, that should be merged, is varying.
It is difficult to explain, so here is an example to show what I mean:

```
Same values | 1 | Date | City
Same values | 2 | Date | City
Same values | 3 | Date | City
```

This should be converted to something like this:

```
Same values | Date1 | City1 | Date2 | …
```

So, I basically want to access all data as simple as possible. Do you have a simple solution?

Comment: With variable column count? No.

Comment: There are hundreds of variations of this question with answers if you search SO for [PIVOT SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Pivot+SQLite). You should be able to find what you need there.

Comment: No… I know that variables are not possible. This is just an example to explain my problem.

Comment: this is equivalent to saying that you want to convert a vertical table to a horizontal table. You might need a view such that each row is converted to a column. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table is like so (I have added column names):

```
A           | B |    C     |  D
------------+---+----------+------
Same values | 1 | 20130101 | City1
Same values | 2 | 20130102 | City2
Same values | 3 | 20130103 | City3
```

Your query would be:

```
SELECT  A,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN C END) C1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 1 THEN D END) D1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 2 THEN C END) C1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 2 THEN D END) D1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 3 THEN C END) C1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN B = 3 THEN D END) D1
FROM    T
GROUP BY A;
```

**[Example On SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/785d2/1)**

Which gives:

```
A            |  C1       |  D1    | C1       |  D1    | C1       |  D1
-------------+-----------+--------+----------+--------+----------+--------
Same values  |  20130101 |  City1 | 20130102 |  City2 | 20130103 |  City3
```

As far as I know SQLite does not support dynamic SQL, so if you don't know how many columns you will need until run time you will need to build your query in your application layer, then send it to the database.

So you would need to get the maximum value for B:

```
SELECT MAX(B) B FROM T;
```

Then loop through 1 to the Max Value of B (I don't know what language you are using, but in C# as it is what I am using today):

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var template = ", MAX(CASE WHEN B = {0} THEN C END) C{0}, MAX(CASE WHEN B = {0} THEN D END) D{0}";
sb.Append("SELECT A");

for (int i = 1; i < MaxB; i++) {
    sb.Append(string.Format(template, i);
}
sb.Append(" FROM T GROUP BY A");
```